# How to set up SSL load balancing to one container in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kube deployment in GKE and I have one pod that acts as a gateway.

How can I setup SSL and load balancing onto that one pod?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You read any of the documentation? Any particular issues that you've come across?

Comment: @Harmelodic So im trying to follow this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ but it doesn't say anywhere to attach it to a single pod on GKE

Comment: Right, so you're looking at the Google COMPUTE Engine documentation, which isn't related to Google Container Engine or Kubernetes.

You'll want to read up on Kubernetes Services ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ ) for Networking and Load Balancing, then read up on Kubernetes Ingress ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ ) for managing external access to Kubernetes Services.

Google also provide references to using HTTPs Load Balancers with Ingress: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer